# Do I need to reference Entity Framework everywhere I use my Data Context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference

I have two projects in my solution - `Api` and `Models`. Models have `MainDataContext` that works just fine. I referenced my `Models` project in my `Api` project so I can access my models.

Problem is it is saying I need to reference Entity Framework in my `Api` as well with all the connection strings etc.. I don't understand why I need to reference it in my `Api` if it is using `Models` project that already has everything set up.

It seems I need to duplicate connection strings, configurations, references, etc.. What is the point of creating separate project for data access (models) then?

## Image with project structure

[image]

Comment: Post some sample code, or a picture showing an example of how your solution is organized (from solution explorer or so). Also, yes, if you intend to query an Entity Framework context (regardless of where from) you need a reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll`, That's why I separate the context itself from the actual entities in my projects and reference the context (and Entity Framework) only in my DAO layer.

Comment: @HighCore Yea I didn't thought about that. It's even better to leave models to just be models w/o any connection to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 options here:

1 - Instead of exposing the Entity Framework context in your Model project, create an intermediate layer  of abstraction that allows you to query the context indirectly. There are plenty of examples in the web about this.

2 - Separate the Context from the Entities themselves and have the Entities in a common layer throughtout the solution, while the Context lives specifically in the Data Access layer